# MySQL query: Trying to join likes

Tags: mysql

OBJECTIVE: Want to show books, book like count, authors, and author like count.

[image: MODEL]

```
-- books: start
SELECT * FROM books
-- likes: get like count of books
JOIN likes ON likes.id = books.likes_id
-- merge table: join to book
JOIN authors_books ON books.id = authors_books.book_id
-- authors: join merge table
JOIN authors ON authors.id = authors_books.author_id
-- likes: get like count of authors
JOIN ????????
```

[image: RESULTS GRID]

I'm stuck at authors likes.
Instead of likes_id:
I would like likes_count (see RESULTS GRID image).

I tried:

> JOIN likes AS l2 ON likes.id = authors.likes_id

No luck. Shows all the correct column info at the top, but blank output.

Comment: use COUNT(authors.likes_id)

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), especially of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RaushanKumar It's not a one-to-many relationship. The count is in `likes.count` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join with `likes` twice, once for the book, another for the author.

Since you join with the same table, you need to give them aliases to distinguish them.

```
SELECT books.id, books.title, books.pages, book_likes.count AS book_likes, 
       authors.first_name, author.last_name, author_likes.count AS author_likes
FROM books
JOIN likes AS book_likes ON book_likes.id = books.likes_id
JOIN authors_books ON books.id = authors_books.book_id
JOIN authors ON authors.id = authors_books.author_id
JOIN likes AS author_likes ON author_likes.id = authors.likes_id
```

Comment: Thank you! I just did an excersize like this... 
Of course after I make the question lol. 
Specifying and setting variables as unique really did the trick!

Comment: You're awesome!